# Is it better to share pages with normal user and admin?

Tags: laravel, admin

I am new to web development but I have some experience in VB.Net desktop app programming. The software I am currently maintaining is only accessible within the company office network. Now that the management demanded the software to be accessible online, I have no choice but to convert it as a web-based system.

I had already started developing the software using laravel framework and so far so good. I successfully created the login form, few pages with CRUD implementation.

However, I came to a confusing part of development stage where I want to prevent some type of users from editing/adding/deleting records. Basically, there are two type of users I'm using which are Administrator and Normal User.

I already made many sections and pages, and I'm thinking of creating a duplicate version of these pages and folders for normal users only. This way I can remove some of the edit/delete/etc from the pages that are not needed for the user. But I'm still in dilemma because if I create duplicates for these pages, it would be tiresome to make changes in future when maintaining it.

So, what do you guys think? should I make a modified copy of the pages or just use the same pages for all users and disable some features based on user type?

Comment: ofcourse, it is bad habit to make copy of the pages in your scenairo. You can manage pages based on user's roles easily. There are plenty of good packages out there. I generally use this one : https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: thanks for your feedback. yes, I'm thinking the same. I will try to learn more about laravel permission since this is the better approach. thanks..